# jQueryMobile: Button on header is half height

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I placed a button in the header of a page and it renders half the height. As well, there is a width gap to the right.

I have used fairly simple jQueryMobel syntax.

URL: http://sandapps.com/Data/Mobile_Energy_Oil_Gas_Pertroleum_Coal_Solar_Wind.aspx

On an iPhone 4S:

[image]

Comment: I don't get the gap on the right.

Comment: Looks like you got it fixed-up, the `notext` icons really do look good when they work. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to create buttons without text using the jQuery Mobile framework and without hacking the framework's CSS. I do often and I haven't had them display like yours. For icons without text I believe you are supposed to declare: `data-iconpos="notext"` as an attribute for the anchor tag:

```
<div data-role="header">
    <h1>...</h1>
    <a href="#" data-iconpos="notext" data-icon="home">Some Text That Won't Display</a>
</div>
```

*Source: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/buttons/buttons-icons.html*

Here is a demo using the same `<a>` code as above: http://jsfiddle.net/3njz7/

Also note that you can have text in your anchor tag if you set the `data-iconpos` attribute to `notext`.

Answer (score 1):

Provide a height to the span which you have used to show the home button. `10px` height works fine try with that.

I don't see any white space on the right side.

Comment: It's a `span`, so if you want to set a height, you'll also need to set `display:block` or `inline-block`.

Comment: @TimothyAaron - The `span` is already `display:block` in the site so I  gave this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Add a space to the button text. http://screencast.com/t/rJ40PGjn42

Comment: As long as setting `display:block` doesn't break anything, that plus `height:10px` works great, too -- as ShankarSangoli suggests.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
data-iconshadow="false" data-iconpos="notext"
```